# Ports for Hive on AWS EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-emr

I created 1 node EMR (master only) with Hive.

After opening inbound port 22 I can SSH to EMR and type `hive` and can open and run SQL queries.

How to `curl` hive from inside of EMR - locally? (which URL / port should use?)

How to access Hive from outside of EMR? (which URL / port should use?)

Comment: Hive runs of 10000 by default

Comment: Yes, but I need it on 443.

Answer (score 0):

It should be on port 443 as rest api for hive needs to be ssl encrypted.
Please check details over [here](https://developers.hive.com/reference#introduction)

In terms of url you need to check your AWS config, and usually you call the EMR API as per details in [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html) and from there you call the hive commands.

Comment: It is not on 443 by default. It is on 10000.

Comment: 10000 is for the https:// based hive via ambari or any other visual interface. i dont think the api has the same port